# Can I enchant a Trident with Channeling?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My Enchantment Table has level 30 enchantments, I have tried to get Channeling with my tridents but it never seems to come up.

Is it possible to enchant a Trident with Channeling directly? Otherwise, how do I get a Channeling enchanted book?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You **can** get channeling from enchant tables, and in your case, you are simply just unlucky.

> Channeling is available from enchantment tables, raid drops,<sup>‌[Bedrock Edition only]</sup> books obtained by fishing, minecart chests, librarian villagers, and from chests found in Overworld non-village structures.

If you want channeling desperately, you can try via other methods such as [fishing](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Fishing) , by [raid drops](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Raid) or by [trading](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Trading).

If this does not answer your question, you can go [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Channeling) to find out more

Hope this would help!